# Python logger exclude modules

Tags: python, python-logging

My main script `DAILY-DATA` contains below logger module configuration.

```
# Get the name of each script without extension to include in log file
class ContextFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        record.filename = record.filename[:-3].upper()
        return True
# Define logging function
    def setup_logging():
        log_basename = "/home/algotrading/daily-data/logs/daily-data"  # location of log file
        log_format = f'%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(filename)s - %(message)s'
        logging.basicConfig(filename=f"{log_basename}_{dt.now().strftime('%Y%m%d-%H_%M_%S')}.log", level=logging.INFO,
                            format=log_format)
        f = ContextFilter()
        logging.getLogger().addFilter(f)
<rest of my code>
```

This main script will import additional scripts like `login`, `telegrambot`. I want to create a common log file from all this module.

telegrambot.py

```
import telegram
import asyncio
import logging


TOKEN = 'token'
chat_id = 'id'


async def send_telegram_message(msg):
    bot = telegram.Bot(TOKEN)
    logging.info(f"Sending telegram notification")
    try:
        async with bot:
            response = await bot.send_message(text=msg, chat_id=chat_id)
            if response and response.message_id:
                logging.info(f"Successfully sent telegram notification")
            else:
                logging.error("Telegram notification is failed to send.")
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(
            f"Failed to send telegram notification.Function - send_telegram_message.Exception: {str(e)}")
```

Sample log file :

```
2023-10-24 14:50:01,199 - INFO - TELEGRAMBOT - Sending telegram notification
2023-10-24 14:50:01,843 - INFO - _client.py - HTTP Request: POST https://api.telegram.org/bot6xxxxx/getMe "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
2023-10-24 14:50:02,277 - INFO - _client.py - HTTP Request: POST https://api.telegram.org/bot6xxxxxx/sendMessage "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
2023-10-24 14:50:02,280 - INFO - TELEGRAMBOT - Successfully sent telegram notification
2023-10-24 14:50:02,284 - INFO - LOGIN - Trying to get Request key
2023-10-24 14:50:02,662 - INFO - LOGIN - Successfully retrieved the Request key
2023-10-24 14:50:02,663 - INFO - LOGIN - Trying to validate TOTP - Attempt - 1
2023-10-24 14:50:03,085 - INFO - LOGIN - Successfully verified TOTP
2023-10-24 14:50:03,085 - INFO - LOGIN - Trying to generate access token
2023-10-24 14:50:04,385 - INFO - LOGIN - Successfully generated access token
2023-10-24 14:50:04,389 - INFO - LOGIN - Initiating user authentication to Fyers
2023-10-24 14:50:04,673 - INFO - LOGIN - Successfully authenticated user
2023-10-24 14:50:04,673 - INFO - DAILY-DATA - Trying to fetch historical spot data of FINNIFTY from date 2023-10-24 to 2023-10-24
2023-10-24 14:50:04,963 - INFO- DAILY-DATA - Fetched historical spot data of FINNIFTY
2023-10-24 14:50:05,112 - INFO - TELEGRAMBOT - Sending telegram notification
2023-10-24 14:50:05,760 - INFO - _client.py - HTTP Request: POST https://api.telegram.org/bot6xxxxx/getMe "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
2023-10-24 14:50:06,167 - INFO - _client.py - HTTP Request: POST https://api.telegram.org/bot6xxxxx/sendMessage "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
2023-10-24 14:50:06,168 - INFO - TELEGRAMBOT - Successfully sent telegram notification
```

How can I exclude the logs which I am not exclusively capturing ? For example above log file is capturing the HTTP post request from telegram api. I dont want to capture those, instead I need only the one which I mentioned.